# How to define a class that does not have two equivalent predicate objects?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

I'm trying to define class of intervals. Each interval object may have (optionally) at most two boundary points. One of them - lower boundary, and another - upper boundary. How can I restrict my class of intervals, so that lower and upper individual boundary points must be different (if provided)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare that the **hasLowerBound** and **hasUpperBound** properties are disjoint.  This means that an individual with values for both cannot have the *same* value for both.  Here's an example.  I've used an object property here, but you can use disjoint property axioms with datatype properties, too.

[image: disjoint property axiom in protege]

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/#hasLowerBound>
        a                         owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyDisjointWith  <http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/#hasUpperBound> .

<http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/#hasUpperBound>
        a       owl:ObjectProperty .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/#hasUpperBound"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/#hasLowerBound">
    <owl:propertyDisjointWith rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/36043590/1281433/#hasUpperBound"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thinking about the problem over night, I would like to modify the desired axiom. Let's state that the class of intervals is a subclass of extents. So, I would like to say that the class of intervals is an equivalent of [], which has at most two boundary points (one - the lower, and another - the upper) which are different (individual points are not the same). In this situation an individual member of (instance of) the class 'extent' can have lower and upper boundary points which are the same individual. But in this case the given extent's individual doesn't belong to the class of intervals.

Comment: In that case I probably cannot declare that predicates (properties) lower and upper boundary points are disjointed. Because if they are disjointed the complement of extent class without interval class becomes empty. But I would to make this class as a class of points (in other words a special class of intervals for which lower and upper boundary points are the same).

Comment: @Alex do you want to say that "**if** an extent is an has different endpoints **then** it is an interval" or "**if** something is an extent, **then** it's endpoints must differ"?

Comment: I think the first. If an extent has different endpoints then it is an interval. The second step - if an extent has endpoints which happens to be the same individual - this extent is a point.

Comment: @Alex Hmmm.... you can definitely do that in a SWRL rule, but I don't think you can do that in an owl axiom.

Comment: and an extent could have at most 2 endpoints (one of then - lower boundary, and another - upper boundary).

Comment: As @JoshuaTaylor said, you'll need SWRL. OWL does not have variables and class expressions have a tree-like structure.